# Particle Sphere not fully drawn when looping through vertices

Tags: three.js

I am drawing a sphere in THREEJS with particles. That works good.

However i loop trough those points to animate(reposition them). Works just fine when i use widthSegments under 50(WidthSegement is the 2nd argument). Anything above 50 will stop being drawn.

For reference:

```
SphereGeometry(radius, widthSegments, heightSegments)
```

This would work fine:

```
let geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(30, 50, 20);
```

And produce this effect: [image: Sphere with arguments(30,50,20)]

if i go with like 100 segments for example i would get this result:
[image]

However this only happens when i loop trough the points to alter their position.

It still animates the existing points. but not any others.

```js
//Related to the audio api
let AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext,
  ctxAudio = new AudioContext(),
  sampleRate = ctxAudio.sampleRate,
  audio = document.getElementById("sound"),
  audioSrc = ctxAudio.createMediaElementSource(audio),
  analyser = ctxAudio.createAnalyser(),
  bufferLength = analyser.frequencyBinCount,
  dataArray = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);
analyser.fftSize = 2048 * 2;
analyser.smoothingTimeConstant = 0.75;
audioSrc.connect(analyser);
audioSrc.connect(ctxAudio.destination);

//Setting up the renderer
let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

//Defining the objects in the scene
let geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(30, 100, 20);
let loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
loader.crossOrigin = true;
let particleTexture = loader.load('https://threejs.org/examples/textures/particle2.png');
let material = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
  color: 0x20C9BD,
  size: 1,
  transparent: true,
  blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
  map: particleTexture,
  depthWrite: false
});

let points = new THREE.Points(geometry, material);
let scene = new THREE.Scene();
let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);


//Setting the scene
scene.add(points);
camera.position.z = 100;

//Copy the default sphere into a vector
const def = new THREE.Vector3;
for (let i = 0; i < geometry.vertices.length; i++) {
  def[i] = {
    x: geometry.vertices[i].x,
    y: geometry.vertices[i].y,
    z: geometry.vertices[i].z
  };
}

//Render the scene(looping through it 60 times a second)
//This is where the issue is
function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  analyser.getByteFrequencyData(dataArray);
  camera.lookAt(points.position);
  for (let i = 0; i < geometry.vertices.length; i++) {
    let particle = geometry.vertices[i];
    let dx = def[i].x * (dataArray[i] / 255.0) + def[i].x;
    let dy = def[i].y * (dataArray[i] / 255.0) + def[i].y;
    let dz = def[i].z * (dataArray[i] / 255.0) + def[i].z;
    particle.set(dx, dy, dz); //<--this is where the issue is.
  }
  geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
render();
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/build/three.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <script src="../js/three.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <audio id="sound" controls src="http://tackj.happyvisocoders.be/audio/DieForYou-Starset.mp3"></audio>
</body>

</html>
```

If you comment out the particle.set(dx,dy,dz) it draws perfectly.
However this animates the particles to move along with the music. So its important to keep this part.

Why doesn't the sphere draw completly and how can i fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has in fact little to do with three.js but more with the webaudio-API.

When you are creating the analyzer with an FFT-size of 2048, you will get 1024 frequency bins (see `analyzer.frequencyBinCount`), but your geometry has 1902 vertices. So for vertices with index 1024 to 1901, `dataArray[i]` is undefined, and the calculations all resolve to `NaN`. Now you are setting the vector as `vector.set(NaN, NaN, NaN)` and three.js has no Idea what to make of this so the points don't get rendered.

So if you replace that part of the loop with

```
let fftValue = (dataArray[i] / 255.0) || 0;
let dx = def[i].x * fftValue + def[i].x;
let dy = def[i].y * fftValue + def[i].y;
let dz = def[i].z * fftValue + def[i].z;
particle.set(dx, dy, dz);
```

or even simpler:

```
let fftValue = (dataArray[i] / 255.0) || 0;
geometry.vertices[i]
  .copy(def)
  .multiplyScalar(1 + fftValue)
```

you should be alright.

Comment: Ah yeah ofc... how did i not think of that! Thanks for the help.

Comment: completely unrelated, when doing stuff like this with javascript, would having `data * inv255` instead of dividing by 255 do the same?

Comment: mostly I guess. I was like "JS engines should be smart enough to treat both cases the same"... But then this happened: https://jsperf.com/fixed-division-vs-inverse-multiplication/1 – blown away, thanks @pailhead :D

Comment: @MartinSchuhfuß what if I wanted to make use of all points. Like if the amount of points is greater than the frequencyBinCount. but still want to animate all points. lets say we can animate 1000 points but there are 2000. how would i loop trough the data in reverse? to give it a nice effect.

Comment: @DarkEyeDragon perhaps ask another question?